# 3d cube rotation jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-animate

http://www.melonhtml5.com/#gallery.js

i am planning to implement this site for my current project for both desktop and mobile versions
is it possible to implement the same 3d animation using jquery mobile for iphone and ipad device using jquery mobile

providing code from the actual site

```
@media screen and (min-height: 450px) and (max-height: 720px) {
    #widget_scroll_container {
        width: 1660px;
    }
    div.widget_container {
        margin-right: 50px;
        width: 900px;
    }
    div.widget_container.half {
        width: 300px;
    }
    div.widget1x1 {
        width: 65px;
        height: 65px;
    }
    div.widget2x2 {
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
    }
    div.widget4x2 {
        width: 290px;
        height: 140px;
    }
    div.widget1x1:hover {
        width: 59px;
        height: 59px;
    }
    div.widget2x2:hover {
        width: 134px;
        height: 134px;
    }
    div.widget4x2:hover {
        width: 284px;
        height: 134px;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blazemonger: thanks for your reply...do you have any online example for jquery mobile

Comment: @user1943618 What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jasper: if there is any available online example i can work on it...right now i am copying the code from the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VGgZ3/